# Sequencing of river network calculation using sfnetworks and r

Tags: r, geospatial, graph-theory, tidygraph, sfnetwork

I’ve got a rooted tree setup in `sfnetworks`. It is derived from a line shapefile of a stream network. For each tributary in the stream network, there are obviously start and end nodes which `sfnetworks` determines, but there are also nodes connecting between start and end nodes on the line. I am going to take the example network developed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958776/group-id-for-all-edges-between-points-using-sfnetwork-in-r) for simplicity sake.

```
library(sfnetworks)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
rm(list = ls())

n01 = st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))
n02 = st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 2)))
n03 = st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 3)))
n04 = st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 4)))
n05 = st_sfc(st_point(c(2, 1)))
n06 = st_sfc(st_point(c(2, 3)))
n07 = st_sfc(st_point(c(2, 4)))
n08 = st_sfc(st_point(c(3, 2)))
n09 = st_sfc(st_point(c(3, 3)))
n10 = st_sfc(st_point(c(3, 4)))
n11 = st_sfc(st_point(c(4, 2)))
n12 = st_sfc(st_point(c(4, 4)))

from = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9, 9)
to = c(5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 11, 10, 12)

nodes = st_as_sf(c(n01, n02, n03, n04, n05, n06, n07, n08, n09, n10, n11, n12)) 
edges = data.frame(from = from, to = to)


G_1 = sfnetwork(nodes, edges)%>%
  convert(to_spatial_explicit, .clean = TRUE) %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  mutate(edgeID = c("a","c","d","e","f","b","g","h","i","j","k")) %>%
  mutate(dL = c(1100, 300, 100, 100, 100, 500, 500, 300, 100, 100, 100))  


ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = G_1 %>% activate(edges) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf(), aes(color = factor(edgeID)), size = 1.5)+
  geom_sf(data = G_1 %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble() %>% st_as_sf())+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")+
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", color = "EdgeID")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I am working on a solving an equation as you move upstream on a stream, starting at the river outlet. I'll save you as much of the details on that equation as I can, but essentially:

I am solving for `hx` at each node, x, based on node attributes.

```
hx = sqrt(h0^2 + (N*dX/K)*(2*L – dX))
```

- `N`, `dX`, `K`, and `L` are all fixed parameters known before we start the calculation.
- `N`, `K` are fixed for all nodes, they never change.
- `dX` is a node specific attribute.
- `h0` and `L` are edge specific attributes (they are the same for all nodes on an edge)
- `h0` is defined by the user at the start of the calculation, but then changes as you traverse the network upstream, changing at the end node when new edges converge.
- `h0` is initially set to 10, N = 0.5, K = 1500.
- For sake of simplicity of presenting this, we will say that each edge is 100m long.
- `dX` just reflects the distance on each edge. The downstream node on each edge, `dX = 0`. The upstream node on each edge, `dX = 100`.
- `L` reflects the total distance of channel upstream of an `edge`, plus the total length of that `edge`.

I want to start the calculation at the downstream node of *edge a* with `h0 = 10`.

1. `hx` is calculated at that starting point and then at every node along the edge (in this example only the starting and ending node is shown) until you get to the junction where *edge g* and *edge b* merge to form *edge a*.
2. At that end point of *edge a*:

```
hx = sqrt(10^2 + (0.5*100/1500)*(2*1100-100)).
hx = 13.03
```

3. At this junction of *edge g* and *edge b*, I want to update `h0` to reflect the `hx` calculated at the end point of *edge a*, so 13.03. This `hx` value will be used as `h0` for both *edge g* and *edge b*.
4. I now want to make this calculation for each subnetwork. I will start with the subnetwork that starts at *edge b*. `h0` has been changed to 13.03, we calculate `hx` for the nodes on *edge b*, then get to the junction of *edge c* and *edge d*.
5. At that end point of *edge b*:

```
hx = sqrt(13.03^2 + (0.5*100/1500)*(2*500-100))
hx = 14.13
```

6. `h0` is updated for both *edge c* and *edge d* so that it reflects `hx` of *edge b*’s endpoint (14.13)
7. `hx` is calculated for all nodes on *edge d*, and again on *edge c*.
8. At the endpoint of *edge c*, `h0` is updated to reflect the `hx` at that junction of *edge e* and *edge f*

```
hx = sqrt(14.13^2+(0.5*100/1500)*(2*300 – 100))
hx = 14.79
```

9. `hx` is finally calculated for all the nodes on *edge e* and *edge f*, using that `hx` calculated at the endpoint of *edge c* for the `h0`. That completes the traversal of that subnetwork.
10. We return to *edge g* to calculate `hx` for the subnetwork that begins there.
11. As we know from previous calculations, `hx` at the endpoint of *edge a* is 13.03. We now want `h0` to again reflect this value for the beginning of the traversal of the subnetwork starting at *edge g*.
12. When we get to the node junction at *edges h* and *edge i*, again, we update `h0` to reflect the `hx` calculated at the end point of *edge g*.

```
hx = sqrt(13.03^2 +(0.5*100/1500)*(2*500-100))
hx = 14.13
```

13. This is the value used as `h0` for *edges h* and *edge i*. We calculate `hx` on *edge i* and then on *edge h*. `h0` is updated a final time where *edge j* and *edge k* merge to reflect the `hx` calculated at the endpoint of *edge h*.

```
hx = sqrt(14.13^2 + (0.5*100/1500)*(2*500-100))
hx = 14.79
```

After that final update to `h0`, `hx` is calculated for all nodes on *edge j* and *edge k*.

In gist, `h0` needs to be updated as you move upstream to new edges to reflect the maximum `hx` of the immediate downstream edge. There is a certain order of solution that must be achieved in that, before solving any edge (outside of the first edge), you need to know the `ho` for that segment, meaning you have to solve the edge below first, to determine the `hx` to use.

I have struggled to come up with a loop/iteration/recursion solution to this calculation that at the surface seems like it should be quite easily solved. The solution along a single drainage thread is very easy to do manually, but when it is scaled up to a whole network there are these sequencing concerns that must be addressed. When you have many thousand of edges in a network, manually making these calculations would not be an option.

This type of calculation sequencing is quite common in many basic hydrologic analyses (calculating stream order, stream magnitude, calculating upstream contributing area, etc.).
`sfnetworks` and  `tidygraph` seem well suited to make this type of calculation but there are few  example applications on hydrologic networks (most tools for graph analysis are geared for road networks which,  given the difference in terms of number of users, makes complete sense).

I tried to make this as much of a repex as possible, if more is needed I will happily supply that, it was difficult to do given the more conceptual nature of the question.

Comment: Hi @scott did you get anywhere with this? I'm interested in deriving stream order using sfnetwork.

Comment: Hey @JoshJ, never came up with a solution in sfnetwork. Essentially had to come up with a work around using stream order as the basis.

Comment: Got a work around for strahler order in case you're interested @Scott R
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203678/strahler-stream-order-using-igraph-or-sfnetwork-in-r?noredirect=1#comment127868515_72203678

Comment: @JoshJ This is great. Like I said, I essentially brute forced my needs by copy and pasting the same code for orders 1-7. It works, but definitely needs to be incorporated into a solution like this.